# Не срабатывает z-index на блок

Tags: html, css3, z-index

Никак не получается сделать наложение текста абзацев на блок меню.
Почему при задании блоку стилей

```css
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

А у меню z-index: 2; и position: fixed;

[сайт с проблемой](http://modern.codenames-zero.ru)

Скрин - http://joxi.ru/82QxyR7Uj7jBbm

Comment: `position: relative;` с этим работает, но по адресу, указанному вами этого стиля нет

Comment: В том то и дело, что не работает с этим) Добавьте в инспектор и покажите на скрине как это работает и я заберу свои слова обратно) А стиля нет, потому что я его убрал, потому что он не работает

Comment: работает весь блок `.container`, но не абзацы текста. Текст и боковая панель находятся в разных контейнерах и текст над боковой панелью вы не поднимете